# Codeigniter dynamic routing for webapp

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create dynamic routes on my web application, but i've got a routing issue.

Here's my URL : 
https://www.mywebsite.fr/Template/index/Albumaker/10212276203435022

I want something that looks like this :

https://www.mywebsite.fr/Albumaker

I've tried this on my routes but it does not work :

```
$route['Template/index/(:any)/(:num)'] = '$1';
```

Any idea, thanks ?

Comment: You should learn how [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) works in codeigniter. You didn't even specify the controller that should process that route.

Comment: huh means i am forced to create a controller and a method for each dynamic content ?

Comment: Well, something needs to process the request. I'm not saying create a new, but you _need_ to have one responsible for handling the requests made to that route - and by that I mean either create a controller/method or use an existing one.

Comment: I don't understand your comment but since you accepted the answer below I'll assume it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use two parameters in your controller for your `index()` function, you need those two params in your URL. Otherwise, you should edit your controller to use one parameter.

But you're doing stuff in the wrong order, this is the right way:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Template/index/$1';
```

It will not work with your current controller. But this will work:

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'Template/index/$1/$2';
```

With this url: https://www.mywebsite.fr/Albumaker/10212276203435022

Comment: Thanks man ! I'll get rid of the 2nd parameter and it will be perfect, I have to learn how making routes

Comment: You'll find every thing you need to know about Routing in the [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).